# How to create a PostgreSQL column that is a set of enum values?

Tags: postgresql, types, enums

I like that I can create [new enum types in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/datatype-enum.html).  But what if I want a column value that is a *set* of enum values.  Do I need to implement that manually with an integer column type and bitwise operators, or is there a way to keep using the enums by name?

```
CREATE TYPE foo AS ENUM ('none', 'loud', 'bright', 'cheap')
CREATE TABLE t (
    id serial,
    properties [set of foo?]
)
...
SELECT * FROM t;
1      loud
2      loud, cheap
3      bright
4      none
...
```

Comment: What's wrong with a standard association table for this?

Comment: That's probably what I'll end up doing. I would have liked this because it would check the type for me.  I guess I could add a check constraint to get the same safety, but that would then have to select from the association table every time, or it would have to contain hard coded integers, duplicating the definitions in the association table.  Is that right?  How would you do it?

Comment: Keep the enum and use an association table with `integer` and `foo` columns to hold the properties. There's nothing wrong with joining to the association table, I suppose you could use `array_agg` if you wanted to pull them all out in column.

Comment: @mu is too short There are two problems with table ascociation: 1) You cant index rows based on weather they have a particular property. 2) It makes a lot of your queries more complex *although that's a minor complaint*.

Comment: @couling: But you will (or at least should) have an index in the assoc table so property existence is fast and trivial to check. And the occasional join will probably be a lot simpler than all the extra complexity of dealing with an array or other kludge.

Comment: @mu is too short Firstly that **doesn't** index the main table and **can't**. You can't index a table based on rows in another table. Separate tables force table joins which can be huge no matter what indexes you use (*not "trivial" as you suggest*). There is an enormous difference between storing all your data physically in the same place (array column) vs spreading it across multiple tables and many rows (associated table). Separating the tables spreads your 1 "record" across many DB pages which may not even be near each other on disk. The DB must work to reassemble the data before using it.

Comment: @couling: Firstly, you need to relax a little. Secondly, arrays are variably sized so there's no reason to think that an array value will be stored with the rest of the row, I'd expect at least one level of redirection in the row when an array is involved. I'm pretty sure PostgreSQL can join to a properly indexed assoc table without much difficulty. Benchmarks of the two approaches would be a lot more interesting than arguing hypotheticals in a comment thread.

Comment: @mu is too short I'm quite calm, just a little assertive.  I agree about the benchmarks. Big table joins on big tables are bad no matter how you index it.  If you're looking up 1 row its trivial. If your joining 25% of two BIG tables together it's a different story - especially when there are already other tables in the query. Postgres only stores strings elsewhere when they are very large. I'd be surprised if shorter arrays are not stored locally.  Also the array itself is likely to be on one page (if it will fit). Multiple rows have a high chance of not being thus is more fragmented.

Comment: @mu is too short finally a query which pulls out every row with its properties would be complex to construct with multiple tables. Most likely it would take two queries by the app; one for the main table and repeated calls to pull out each rows list of properties.  I don't agree that the equivalent with arrays would be more complex when I've implemented this myself for a previous app and know it to be trivial.

Comment: two words: bit fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array:

```
CREATE TYPE foo AS ENUM ('none', 'loud', 'bright', 'cheap');
CREATE TABLE t (
    id serial,
    properties foo[]
);
```

Comment: But an array is not a set, using an array means that you have to deal with duplicates yourself (possibly using triggers) and add CHECKs to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: would a bitmask enum make more sense in this scenario?